# Open and read .eml files with VBA

Tags: vba, parsing, eml

I need to open and read .eml files using VBA. Shockingly this seems to be difficult. Please help. The below code gives this error at line `Set OL = GetObject("Outlook.Application")`:

> Run-time error '-2147221020 (800401e4)': 
>   Automation error 
>   Invalid Syntax

Code:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1
Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Long = 3
Private Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Long = 2

Sub test11()
    strMyFile = "C:\test.eml"
    Dim Myinspect As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OL As Object

    If Dir(strMyFile) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File " & strMyFile & " does not exist"
    Else
        ShellExecute 0, "Open", strMyFile, "", "C:\test1.eml", SW_SHOWNORMAL
    End If

    Set OL = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Myinspect = OL.ActiveInspector
    Set MyItem = Myinspect.CurrentItem
    MsgBox "Subject = " & MyItem.Subject
    MsgBox "Body = " & MyItem.Body
    MyItem.Close 1
End Sub
```

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: Question edited to answer your question

Comment: `Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetObject` function takes the class name as second argument:

```
Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
```

It's `CreateObject` which would take it first:

```
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Note that Outlook will only run one instance, ever. You should be able to call the `CreateObject` function and would not need to use `GetObject`. If Outlook is already open, `CreateObject` will return that instance, if outlook is not already open, it will create one.

Comment: Awesome. You are my hero.